# How to calculate age from date stored as a string using aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have been struggling for a couple days trying to get the solution to this problem but with no luck.

I have a collections with the following structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5336a26b802596dc5b843960"),
    "name" : "jorge",
    "dob" : "19820525"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5336a2bb802596dc5b843961"),
    "name" : "brandon",
    "dob" : "20100623"
}
```

I would like to return only the person that are older than 18 years.

The goal is to run a report that will only display those persons. What is making this so hard is the date field stored as string and not as ISODate. Unfortunately for now i cannot just update the db to  the right datatype and map reduce is not a option. Eventually it will be.

I would like to be what type of hack or workaround i can do to achieve that goal using the current schema and the aggregation framework.

This is what i have tried so far:

```
db.main.aggregate( [ 
    { $project : { name: 1 , 
                  "ageInMillis" : {$subtract : [ISODate(), ISODate("$dob")]} 
                 }
    }
]);
```

The problem with this is that i got this error:

```
Sat Mar 29 17:29:06.575 invalid ISO date at src/mongo/shell/types.js:64
```

The weird thing is that if i hardcode a string in the ISODate constructor it will work but if 
i put the variable with the $dob form the document it gave me that error.

Any help, suggestion will much appreciated.

Comment: There is nothing **weird** here. The aggregation framework does not use JavaScript. Bottom line here is you **should not** store dates as strings. Convert your dates. Also see the [date operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#date-operators) in the manual once you have fixed your dates.

Comment: Can you clarify why can not you just update your documents to a correct format? Because what you ask is actually to create some strange solution just because you do not want to properly save dates.

Comment: @SalvadorDali I completely agree with you. The reason is that what i need is to create a report from a db that another system is already using to manage that information, if a change the data type of the dob field then some functionality on the other system will fail until the code is modified to the new and (CORRECT) isolate datatype. I understand that is the right way to do it. I was just looking for work around that would allow me to generate the report they need by monday and then work on fixing the dob field data type to isolate and work on the other system too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read the reason why you have to stay with your current datatype. I also think that it is kind of stupid to work with strings to save dates (it is hard and useless because you will change them).

So here is a solution for you: leave your old `string-data` field and create a new one, where you will properly convert it to `Date()`. This way your old code will still work correctly, but you will use new date field for you aggregation framework. This will be trivial after [reading this](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/date_range/) and understanding that you have to look for `{"$lte": start}` where start is current date - 18 years.

Comment: Good idea and great advice, this will save me time while maintaining compatibility with the other system in the mean time i can work on migrate all those wrong string dates to ISODate. Thanks.